# Getting results of async recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm generating random usernames. I have to check and make sure that the generated name isn't already in the database. If it is, I want to run the generator again.

Here is my code. It works as long as the username isn't taken initially.

```
   async function generateUsername() {
      var a = ["Original", "Primary", "Inital", "New", "First"];
      var b = ["User", "Student", "Learner", "Name", "BetaTester"];

      var rA = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length);
      var rB = Math.floor(Math.random() * b.length);
      const usernameAttempt = a[rA] + b[rB];
      console.log("this username attempt is: " + usernameAttempt);

      const existingUser = await pool.query(
        "SELECT username from users WHERE username=$1",
        [usernameAttempt]
      );
      console.log("existing user " + existingUser.rowCount);
      if (existingUser.rowCount === 0) {
        return usernameAttempt;
      } else {
        generateUsername();
      }
    }

    const newUsername = await generateUsername().then();
    console.log("my newUsername is: " + newUsername);
```

If the username is taken initially and it has to be run again, it runs until a new username that isn't in the database is created with `usernameAttempt`. This part works fine. I can see that the final  `usernameAttempt` is correctly not in the database. But the results of   `console.log("my newUsername is: " + newUsername);` is undefined, and then `null` is uploaded into the database, instead of the correct username. What am I missing here?

To clarify, I want the result of `newUsername` to be equal to the latest `usernameAttempt`, not undefined. Particularly, after the function has had to repeat itself.

Comment: You need a `return` before the fist recursive `generateUsername()` call. Also, you don't need the `.then` after the `await generateUsername().then();` call

Comment: You mean ` return generateUsername();`? It works! Thank you so much!